# Says that password is incorrect, but it's correct

Tags: php, authentication

I have problem. I've created a system, that I can login with lowercase and capital letters in nickname that exists in mySQL, but if I try to login with lowercase or capital letters it says, that my password is incorrect, but when I try to login with right nickname it logs in, so where is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['jungtis'])) {

    if($_POST['login_slapyvardis'] != "" && $_POST['login_slaptazodis'] != "") {

        $login_slapyvardis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_slapyvardis']);
        $login_slaptazodis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_slaptazodis']);
        $apsaugotaslogin_slaptazodis = md5($login_slaptazodis);

        if($login_sumazintas == $mysqlskc['name']) {

        $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ucp_users WHERE name='$login_slapyvardis'") or die(mysql_error());
        $mysqlskc = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ucp_users WHERE name=LOWER('$login_slapyvardis')"));
        $login_sumazintas = strtolower($login_slapyvardis);

            $mysqli = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql);

            if($mysqli['password'] == $apsaugotaslogin_slaptazodis) {

                $_SESSION['Logged'] = $mysqli['id'];
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                mysql_query("UPDATE ucp_users SET lastip = '$ip' WHERE id = '$mysqli[id]'");
                header('Location: /home');
```

**Note**: I know it is better that I need to use PDO or `mysqli`, but I am using `mysql_` only for now.

Comment: are you storing the name as lower string?

Comment: FYI, md5 should not be used to hash passwords

Comment: Nah... my name storing as Sprunkas, but when trying to login with sprunkas or SPRUNKAS this error is appearing, but when trying to login Sprunkas then no error appears.

P.S bcrypt is best to hash passwords?

Comment: @user2488773 You should try to incorporate a function that, upon registration, (if that's the intention for the script), is to have a function that will take a username and automatically convert all the letters to lowercase, even if they enter **UPPERCASE-lowercase-Mixed** `case`. Then, applying the same for when they login. This can be achieved using the `strtolower()` function.

Comment: @Fred i know, that is good idea, but problem is that nickname displays at lowercase, but i need to display normal nickname, that they registered with all lowercase uppercase

Comment: @user2488773 What do you mean by `normal` nickname, can you elaborate?

Comment: For example:
If registered nickname Sprunkas then display at main page Sprunkas, but not sprunkas

Comment: 1) MD5 is a very weak hash - if you database is grabbed, it won't take too long to generate rainbow tables to identify user's passwords. 2) even a stronger hash should be salted, since there are already pregenerated rainbow tables for shorter length passwords. 3) stop using mysql library and use PDO - although, well done for escaping your input

Comment: is this code complete? I don't see where you output any "incorrect password" message

Comment: This is a little of code only.

Comment: @user2488773 I'm sure there's probably a way to automatically do this in SQL but I don't know how yet, what I use right now is the `strtoupper()` function in PHP. You can then `echo` the username with that. That's all I know at this point in time, till my SQL skills improve.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix your query.

```
$mysqlskc = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ucp_users WHERE LOWER(name)=LOWER('$login_slapyvardis')"));
```

Comment: mysql is not case sensitive by default

Comment: true, unless the collation is set to a `_cs`